# Structure pointer initialization - local variable

Tags: c, pointers, structure

Could anyone please tell me how "hello" is being printed here? As far as my knowledge goes, local variables are uninitialized. Therefore, I thought the else part should be printed but it's happening otherwise. Please help.

```
struct buss{ 
int a;
char b;
};


void main(){

struct buss *p;

if(p==NULL) printf("hello");

else printf("hi");

}
```

Comment: Uninitialized could mean any value - including `NULL`.

Comment: Why do you find it strange? Your uninitialized value just happened to be a null pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't initialize `p` object. Its value is indeterminate.

Reading an uninitialized object is undefined behavior. Undefined behavior means anything can happen. Anything means your program can also crash or print `"nose demons"`.

**EDIT:** as requested in the comments, to the question "is reading an uninitialized object always undefined  behavior?": for C90, see 3.16 in the definition of undefined behavior, for C11, see 6.3.2.1p2 and for C99, see the C Committee answer in [DR#338](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_338.htm).

Comment: for example, it can start raining

Comment: And an indeterminate value is *either an unspecified value or a trap representation*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil *(C11, 6.3.2.1p2) "If the lvalue designates an object of automatic storage duration that could have been declared with the register storage class (never had its address taken), and that object is uninitialized (not declared with an initializer and no assignment to it has been performed prior to use), the behavior is undefined."* All conditions are filled in the OP example: the evaluation of `p` in `p == NULL` is undefined behavior *per se*.

Comment: @EricPostpischil C90 says *"undefined behavior: Behavior upon use [...] or of indeterminately valued objects [...]*. It clearly states that reading an indeterminate valued object is UB. Now a loophole was inserted in C99, and this was corrected in DR#338 http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/dr_338.htm Read near the end from  "Spring 2008". Reading an uninitialized object is *per se* undefined behavior in C. You can still debate that, but still downvoting my answer is unfair.

Comment: @EricPostpischil if you agree, could you also please remove your downvote to this answer?

Answer (score 2):

`p` is an uninitialized pointer and points to somewhere and happens to be `NULL` and hence `"hello"` is printed. @Ouah explains why you shouldn't access `p`.

Comment: "hello" is printed _if_ `p == NULL`.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks, corrected it. Probably time for an eye-check & change my lens :)

Answer (score 1):

Your *p local variable is not initialized, so it can get any value at random (including NULL)

Also, under *some* conditions, *some* compilers *might* initialize this object to NULL, but this is not required by the standard. So you better initialize your objects.

Answer (score 1):

Strictly speaking, this is undefined behavior, because `p` is not initialized. But for security reasons many OSs will not provide a raw (uninitialized) block of memory in the stack or the heap.  So `p` will *always* be `NULL`, in this simple example (if you called many subroutines, it could be different).